# Can you guys look at my java project and give me some tips?

Tags: java, parsing, swing

So I feel like I'm a good coder, but that's from my point of view. Can you take a look at my code and give me some tips or criticize me on my code. Or give me some tips or things to add or make things smaller.

console class

```
        public class console {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

//makes the window/console
window console=new window();

}

}
```

window class

```
        import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

//the main terminal
public class window extends JFrame{
//variables
static JTextArea window;
JTextField input;

//main window for commands and shit
public window(){
//super because it is
super("my Java Console");

//able to call c.parse
final findCommand c=new findCommand();

//the input is set and shit
input = new JTextField();
  input.addActionListener(
     new ActionListener(){
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event){
            input.setText("");
           c.parse(event.getActionCommand());
        }
     }
  );
  add(input, BorderLayout.NORTH);


  //this window is set and shit
  window = new JTextArea();
  window.setEditable(false);
  add(new JScrollPane(window));
  setSize(300,150);
  setVisible(true);
}

}
```

displayInWindow class

```
        public class displayInWindow {

   //display stuff in the window in the window class
public static void display(String s){
   //the JTextArea is the window and one long continues sentence but with \n
    window.window.append(s+"\n");
}

}
```

findCommand class

```
    public class findCommand {

//finds out what command to run
public void parse(String s){
//deletes spaces before and after
s=s.trim();


//splits into an array
String[] cmd=s.split(" ");

//depending on the length of the string array to find how many parameters it has
if(cmd.length==2){
    switch(cmd[0].toLowerCase()){
    //the print command
    case "print":displayInWindow.display(cmd[1]);break;
    //gets a variable that was set
    case "get":displayInWindow.display(basicCommands.get(cmd[1]));
    }


}else if(cmd.length==3){

    //switch is set to the first one and set to lowercase
    switch(cmd[0].toLowerCase()){
    //add
    case "add":displayInWindow.display(basicCommands.add(cmd[1], cmd[2]));break;
    //subtract
    case "subtract":displayInWindow.display(basicCommands.subtract(cmd[1], cmd[2]));break;
    //multiply
    case "multiply":displayInWindow.display(basicCommands.multiply(cmd[1],cmd[2]));break;
    //divide
    case "divide":displayInWindow.display(basicCommands.divide(cmd[1],cmd[2]));break;
    //remainder
    case "remainder":displayInWindow.display(basicCommands.remainder(cmd[1], cmd[2]));break;
    //power
    case "power":displayInWindow.display(basicCommands.power(cmd[1], cmd[2]));break;
    //set
    case "set":displayInWindow.display(basicCommands.set(cmd[1],cmd[2]));break;

    }

    //switch is set to the middle parameter and no need to set it to lowercase
    switch(cmd[1]){
    //adds
    case "+":displayInWindow.display(basicCommands.add(cmd[0], cmd[2]));break;
    //subtracts
    case "-":displayInWindow.display(basicCommands.subtract(cmd[0], cmd[2]));break;
    //multiplys
    case "*":displayInWindow.display(basicCommands.multiply(cmd[0],cmd[2]));break;
    //divides
    case "/":displayInWindow.display(basicCommands.divide(cmd[0],cmd[2]));break;
    //finds the remainder
    case "%":displayInWindow.display(basicCommands.remainder(cmd[0], cmd[2]));break;
    //set
    case "=":displayInWindow.display(basicCommands.set(cmd[0],cmd[2]));break;
    }

}else{
    if(basicCommands.variables.containsKey(s)){
        //if what typed in is a variable
        displayInWindow.display(s+" is "+basicCommands.variables.get(s) );
    }else{
        //if it is just random typing it displays it
        displayInWindow.display(cmd[0]);
    }

}

}
```

basicCommands class

```
import java.util.Hashtable;

public class basicCommands {

//hashtable for set and get
public static Hashtable variables =new Hashtable();

//adds 2 variables
public static String add(String num1,String num2){
    try{
        try{
            if(num1.contains(".")||num2.contains(".")){
                return(num1+" + "+num2+" = "+Double.toString(Double.parseDouble(num1)+Double.parseDouble(num2)));
            }else{
                return(num1+" + "+num2+" = "+Integer.toString(Integer.parseInt(num1)+Integer.parseInt(num2)));
            }
            }catch(Exception e){
                if(variables.get(num1).toString().contains(".")||variables.get(num2).toString().contains(".")){
                    return(num1+" + "+num2+" = "+num2+Double.toString(Double.parseDouble(variables.get(num1).toString())+Double.parseDouble(variables.get(num2).toString())));
                }else{
                    return(num1+" + "+num2+" = "+Integer.toString(Integer.parseInt(variables.get(num1).toString())+Integer.parseInt(variables.get(num2).toString())));
                }
            }
    }catch(Exception e){
        if(variables.containsKey(num1)){
            if(variables.get(num1).toString().contains(".")||num2.contains(".")){
                return(num1+" + "+num2+" = "+Double.toString(Double.parseDouble(variables.get(num1).toString())+Double.parseDouble(num2)));
            }else{
                return(num1+" + "+num2+" = "+Integer.toString(Integer.parseInt(variables.get(num1).toString())+Integer.parseInt(num2)));
            }
        }else{
            if(num1.contains(".")||variables.get(num2).toString().contains(".")){
                return(num1+" + "+num2+" = "+Double.toString(Double.parseDouble(num1))+Double.parseDouble(variables.get(num2).toString()));
            }else{
                return(num1+" + "+num2+" = "+Integer.toString(Integer.parseInt(num1)+Integer.parseInt(variables.get(num2).toString())));
            }
        }
    }






}

//subtracts 2 variables
public static String subtract(String num1,String num2){
    try{
        try{
            if(num1.contains(".")||num2.contains(".")){
                return(num1+" - "+num2+" = "+Double.toString(Double.parseDouble(num1)-Double.parseDouble(num2)));
            }else{
                return(num1+" - "+num2+" = "+Integer.toString(Integer.parseInt(num1)-Integer.parseInt(num2)));
            }
            }catch(Exception e){
                if(variables.get(num1).toString().contains(".")||variables.get(num2).toString().contains(".")){
                    return(num1+" - "+num2+" = "+Double.toString(Double.parseDouble(variables.get(num1).toString())-Double.parseDouble(variables.get(num2).toString())));
                }else{
                    return(num1+" - "+num2+" = "+Integer.toString(Integer.parseInt(variables.get(num1).toString())-Integer.parseInt(variables.get(num2).toString())));
                }
            }
    }catch(Exception e){
        if(variables.containsKey(num1)){
            if(variables.get(num1).toString().contains(".")||num2.contains(".")){
                return(num1+" - "+num2+" = "+Double.toString(Double.parseDouble(variables.get(num1).toString())-Double.parseDouble(num2)));
            }else{
                return(num1+" - "+num2+" = "+Integer.toString(Integer.parseInt(variables.get(num1).toString())-Integer.parseInt(num2)));
            }
        }else{
            if(num1.contains(".")||variables.get(num2).toString().contains(".")){
                return(num1+" - "+num2+" = "+Double.toString(Double.parseDouble(num1)-Double.parseDouble(variables.get(num2).toString())));
            }else{
                return(num1+" - "+num2+" = "+Integer.toString(Integer.parseInt(num1)-Integer.parseInt(variables.get(num2).toString())));
            }
        }
    }




}

//multiplys 2 variables
public static String multiply(String num1,String num2){
    try{
        try{
            if(num1.contains(".")||num2.contains(".")){
                return(num1+" * "+num2+" = "+Double.toString(Double.parseDouble(num1)*Double.parseDouble(num2)));
            }else{
                return(num1+" * "+num2+" = "+Integer.toString(Integer.parseInt(num1)*Integer.parseInt(num2)));
            }
            }catch(Exception e){
                if(variables.get(num1).toString().contains(".")||variables.get(num2).toString().contains(".")){
                    return(num1+" * "+num2+" = "+Double.toString(Double.parseDouble(variables.get(num1).toString())*Double.parseDouble(variables.get(num2).toString())));
                }else{
                    return(num1+" * "+num2+" = "+Integer.toString(Integer.parseInt(variables.get(num1).toString())*Integer.parseInt(variables.get(num2).toString())));
                }
            }
    }catch(Exception e){
        if(variables.containsKey(num1)){
            if(variables.get(num1).toString().contains(".")||num2.contains(".")){
                return(num1+" * "+num2+" = "+Double.toString(Double.parseDouble(variables.get(num1).toString())*Double.parseDouble(num2)));
            }else{
                return(num1+" * "+num2+" = "+Integer.toString(Integer.parseInt(variables.get(num1).toString())*Integer.parseInt(num2)));
            }
        }else{
            if(num1.contains(".")||variables.get(num2).toString().contains(".")){
                return(num1+" * "+num2+" = "+Double.toString(Double.parseDouble(num1)*Double.parseDouble(variables.get(num2).toString())));
            }else{
                return(num1+" * "+num2+" = "+Integer.toString(Integer.parseInt(num1)*Integer.parseInt(variables.get(num2).toString())));
            }
        }
    }



}

//divides 2 variables
public static String divide(String num1,String num2){
    try{
        try{
            if(num1.contains(".")||num2.contains(".")){
                return(num1+" / "+num2+" = "+Double.toString(Double.parseDouble(num1)/Double.parseDouble(num2)));
            }else{
                if(Double.parseDouble(num1)%Double.parseDouble(num2)==0){
                    return(num1+" / "+num2+" = "+Integer.toString(Integer.parseInt(num1)/Integer.parseInt(num2)));
                }else{
                    return(num1+" / "+num2+" = "+Double.toString(Double.parseDouble(num1)/Double.parseDouble(num2)));
                }

            }
            }catch(Exception e){
                if(variables.get(num1).toString().contains(".")||variables.get(num2).toString().contains(".")){
                    return(num1+" / "+num2+" = "+Double.toString(Double.parseDouble(variables.get(num1).toString())/Double.parseDouble(variables.get(num2).toString())));
                }else{
                    if(Double.parseDouble(variables.get(num1).toString())%Double.parseDouble(variables.get(num2).toString())==0){
                        return(num1+" / "+num2+" = "+Integer.toString(Integer.parseInt(variables.get(num1).toString())/Integer.parseInt(variables.get(num2).toString())));
                    }else{
                        return(num1+" / "+num2+" = "+Double.toString(Double.parseDouble(variables.get(num1).toString())/Double.parseDouble(variables.get(num2).toString())));
                    }
                }
            }
    }catch(Exception e){
        if(variables.containsKey(num1)){
            if(variables.get(num1).toString().contains(".")||num2.contains(".")){
                return(num1+" / "+num2+" = "+Double.toString(Double.parseDouble(variables.get(num1).toString())/Double.parseDouble(num2)));
            }else{
                if(Double.parseDouble(variables.get(num1).toString())%Double.parseDouble(num2)==0){
                    return(num1+" / "+num2+" = "+Integer.toString(Integer.parseInt(variables.get(num1).toString())/Integer.parseInt(num2)));
                }else{
                    return(num1+" / "+num2+" = "+Double.toString(Double.parseDouble(variables.get(num1).toString())/Double.parseDouble(num2)));
                }

            }
        }else{
            if(num1.contains(".")||variables.get(num2).toString().contains(".")){
                return(num1+" / "+num2+" = "+Double.toString(Double.parseDouble(num1)/Double.parseDouble(variables.get(num2).toString())));
            }else{
                if(Double.parseDouble(num1)%Double.parseDouble(variables.get(num2).toString())==0){
                    return(num1+" / "+num2+" = "+Integer.toString(Integer.parseInt(num1)/Integer.parseInt(variables.get(num2).toString())));
                }else{
                    return(num1+" / "+num2+" = "+Double.toString(Double.parseDouble(num1)/Double.parseDouble(variables.get(num2).toString())));
                }
            }
        }
    }



}

//finds the remainder
public static String remainder(String num1,String num2){

    try{
        try{
            if(Double.parseDouble(num1)%Double.parseDouble(num2)==0){

                return(num1+" % "+num2+" = "+Integer.toString(0));
            }else{
                return(num1+" % "+num2+" = "+Integer.toString((int) (Double.parseDouble(num1)%Double.parseDouble(num2))));
            }
        }catch(Exception e){
            if(Double.parseDouble(variables.get(num1).toString())%Double.parseDouble(variables.get(num2).toString())==0){

                return(num1+" % "+num2+" = "+Integer.toString(0));
            }else{
                return(num1+" % "+num2+" = "+Integer.toString((int) (Double.parseDouble(variables.get(num1).toString())%Double.parseDouble(variables.get(num2).toString()))));
            }
        }
    }catch(Exception e){
        if(variables.containsKey(num1)){
            if(Double.parseDouble(variables.get(num1).toString())%Double.parseDouble(num2)==0){
                return(num1+" % "+num2+" = "+Integer.toString(0));
            }else{
                return(num1+" % "+num2+" = "+Integer.toString((int)(Double.parseDouble(variables.get(num1).toString())%Double.parseDouble(num2))));
            }
        }else{
            if(Double.parseDouble(num1)%Double.parseDouble(variables.get(num2).toString())==0){
                return(num1+" % "+num2+" = "+Integer.toString(0));
            }else{
                return(num1+" % "+num2+" = "+Integer.toString((int)(Double.parseDouble(num1)%Double.parseDouble(variables.get(num2).toString()))));
            }
        }
    }






}

//powers the first one to the second one
public static String power(String num1,String num2){
    try{
        try{
            if(Math.floor(Math.pow(Double.parseDouble(num1), Double.parseDouble(num2)))==Math.pow(Double.parseDouble(num1), Double.parseDouble(num2))){
                return(num1+" ^ "+num2+" = "+Integer.toString((int)(Math.pow(Double.parseDouble(num1), Double.parseDouble(num2)))));
            }else{
                return(num1+" ^ "+num2+" = "+Double.toString(Math.pow(Double.parseDouble(num1), Double.parseDouble(num2))));
            }
        }catch(Exception e){
            if(Math.floor(Math.pow(Double.parseDouble(variables.get(num1).toString()), Double.parseDouble(variables.get(num2).toString())))==Math.pow(Double.parseDouble(variables.get(num1).toString()), Double.parseDouble(variables.get(num2).toString()))){
                return(num1+" ^ "+num2+" = "+Integer.toString((int)(Math.pow(Double.parseDouble(variables.get(num1).toString()), Double.parseDouble(variables.get(num2).toString())))));
            }else{
                return(num1+" ^ "+num2+" = "+Double.toString(Math.pow(Double.parseDouble(variables.get(num1).toString()), Double.parseDouble(variables.get(num2).toString()))));
            }
        }
    }catch(Exception e){
        if(variables.containsKey(num1)){
            if(Math.floor(Math.pow(Double.parseDouble(variables.get(num1).toString()), Double.parseDouble(num2)))==Math.pow(Double.parseDouble(variables.get(num1).toString()), Double.parseDouble(num2))){
                return(num1+" ^ "+num2+" = "+Integer.toString((int)(Math.pow(Double.parseDouble(variables.get(num1).toString()), Double.parseDouble(num2)))));
            }else{
                return(num1+" ^ "+num2+" = "+Double.toString(Math.pow(Double.parseDouble(variables.get(num1).toString()), Double.parseDouble(num2))));
            }
        }else{
            if(Math.floor(Math.pow(Double.parseDouble(num1), Double.parseDouble(variables.get(num2).toString())))==Math.pow(Double.parseDouble(num1), Double.parseDouble(variables.get(num2).toString()))){
                return(num1+" ^ "+num2+" = "+Integer.toString((int)(Math.pow(Double.parseDouble(num1), Double.parseDouble(variables.get(num2).toString())))));
            }else{
                return(num1+" ^ "+num2+" = "+Double.toString(Math.pow(Double.parseDouble(num1), Double.parseDouble(variables.get(num2).toString()))));
            }
        }
    }




}

//set something in the hashtable
public static String set(String num1,String num2){
    variables.put(num1, num2);
    return(num1+" was set to "+num2);
}

//gets something in a hashtable
public static String get(String num1){
    try{
        return (variables.get(num1).toString());
    }catch(NullPointerException e){
        return(num1+" was not set to anything.");
    }

}


}
```

Comment: Consistent spacing and indenting will help you and the reviewers.

Comment: Look at [Joshua Bloch book](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/effective/), and compare your work and his advices, about switch, StringBulder, catch use, control and other professional practices

Answer (score 5):

Some tips:

- In Java there is a convention - names of classes start with uppercase letter
- Instance variables like `JTextArea` etc. should be private and not static. Static fields should be used very rarely.
- Every Swing component should be created and changed on EDT. Starting point for Swing applications usually looks like this:

---

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                MyFrame frame = new MyFrame();
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
```

- Use proper variable names: if I see variable 'window' I think that it's of type `JFrame`, `JDialog`, `JWindow` etc. for `JTextField` it can be something like 'commandTF', 'commandField', etc.
- Use IDE and use formatter ([Eclipse](http://eclipse.org/), [Netbeans](http://netbeans.org/), etc.)
- `displayInWindow` is unnecessary - too little functionality. You'll end up with so called "spaghetti-code"
- Usually if you have many switch statements with many close in concept cases - replace it with polymorphism (`enum`s are also useful)

Answer (score 4):

*@Xeon* mentioned some good point, and here are some other:

1. Comment like this does not help too much:

   ```
   //splits into an array
   String[] cmd=s.split(" ");
   ```

   If somebody knows Java they understand the code, so the comment is only duplication and noise. Further reading: *Clean Code by Robert C. Martin, Chapter 4: Comments*
2. In your code `String.split` does not handle well if users put two or more spaces between the arguments. I'd use Guava's [`Splitter`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/base/Splitter.html) here. It could [`trimResults`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/base/Splitter.html#trimResults%28%29) and [`omitEmptyStrings`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/base/Splitter.html#omitEmptyStrings%28%29).
3. I'm not completely sure if it could help or not, but I'd check [Apache Commons CLI](http://commons.apache.org/cli/) and try to parse the arguments with this library. The [`hasArgs(int num)`](http://commons.apache.org/cli/api-1.1/org/apache/commons/cli/OptionBuilder.html#hasArgs%28int%29) method looks promising. Further reading: *Effective Java, 2nd Edition, Item 47: Know and use the libraries*
4. Instead of the `Hashtable` use `HashMap` (with type parameters):

   ```
   Map<String, String> variables = new HashMap<String, String>();
   ```

   See: [Differences between HashMap and Hashtable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40471/differences-between-hashmap-and-hashtable)
5. The methods in the `BasicCommands` class have lots of [smells](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_smell):

   1. It's hard to follow because it uses exceptions for ordinary control flow. (*Effective Java, 2nd Edition, Item 57: Use exceptions only for exceptional conditions*)
   2. It contains lots of duplication. For example, `num1 + " + " + num2 + " = "` should be extracted out to a `resultPrefix` local variable.
   3. It uses floating point variables where you may need exact results. (*Effective Java, 2nd Edition, Item 48: Avoid float and double if exact answers are required*; [Why not use Double or Float to represent currency?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3730019/why-not-use-double-or-float-to-represent-currency))

   Using `BigDecimal`s would reduce the necessary code dramatically since it could store non-integer values, so it handles doubles and integers too, therefore you can omit a few conditions.

   ```
   public static String add(final String num1, final String num2) {
       final BigDecimal resolvedNum1 = resolveNumber(num1);
       final BigDecimal resolvedNum2 = resolveNumber(num2);

       return String.format("%s + %s = %s", num1, num2, resolvedNum1.add(resolvedNum2));
   }

   private static BigDecimal resolveNumber(final String number) {
       final String value = variables.get(number);
       if (value != null) {
           return new BigDecimal(value);
       }
       return new BigDecimal(number);
   }
   ```